# Merge data frames on rows without getting duplicate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two small data frames on their row values, but when I do that I get a

```
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(p, q, by = 0, all = TRUE) :
  column name ‘Row.names’ is duplicated in the result
```

Just wondering of a better approach to merge without duplicating the columns. Below are sample dataframes and script I used. I am merging the dataframes using rows

```
p = data.frame(
  `Row.names` = c("(Intercept)", "dem_10", "padult", "page", "ped_05", "piidflag", "pvismin"),
  Estimate = c(2.538, -0.028, -0.115, 0.112, -0.175, 0.112, 0.038),
  "Std Error" = c(0.025, 0.018, 0.017, 0.008, 0.012, 0.03, 0.017),
  "t value" = c(102.717, -1.606, -6.609, 13.822, -14.928, 3.691, 2.299),
  "Pr(t)" = c(0.00, 0.108, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.022), 
  "sig" = c("***", NA ,"***", "***", "***", "***", "*"),
  "2.5%" = c(2.490, -0.063, -0.148, 0.096, -0.198, 0.053, 0.006),
  "97.5%" = c(2.586, 0.006, -0.081, 0.129, -0.152, 0.172, 0.071),
  row.names = c("(Intercept)", "dem_10", "padult", "page", "ped_05", "piidflag", "pvismin"))


q=data.frame(aca = c(1.011890, 1.011780, 1.009398, 1.026352, 1.036663, 1.017238),
           row.names = c("pvismin", "piidflag", "dem_10", "page", "ped_05", "padult"))

# merge on rows
merge(p, q, by=0, all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `Row.names` column in `p`, you probably `merged` before `by=0` or equivalently `by='row.names'`. Now you want again to merge by row names, which will result in another `Row.names` column and hence will be duplicated. So just get rid of `p`'s first column to make it work.

```
merge(p[-1], q, by=0, all=TRUE)
#     Row.names Estimate Std.Error t.value Pr.t.  sig  X2.5. X97.5.      aca
# 1 (Intercept)    2.538     0.025 102.717 0.000  ***  2.490  2.586       NA
# 2      dem_10   -0.028     0.018  -1.606 0.108 <NA> -0.063  0.006 1.009398
# 3      padult   -0.115     0.017  -6.609 0.000  *** -0.148 -0.081 1.017238
# 4        page    0.112     0.008  13.822 0.000  ***  0.096  0.129 1.026352
# 5      ped_05   -0.175     0.012 -14.928 0.000  *** -0.198 -0.152 1.036663
# 6    piidflag    0.112     0.030   3.691 0.000  ***  0.053  0.172 1.011780
# 7     pvismin    0.038     0.017   2.299 0.022    *  0.006  0.071 1.011890
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame` doesn't allow for duplicated row names.  We may create a column from row names and do a join or merge

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
p %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  full_join(q %>%
    rownames_to_column("rn"))
```